# PHP / HTML5 solution to validating emails and sending validated ones to an email address

Tags: php, validation, email, html, input

Can someone recommend a good php mailer that sends the contents of this single input

```
    <form method="POST" action="mailer.php">
       <div id="emailform"><input type="text" name="email" class="keywords" placeholder="example@example.com" id="subscribetext"></div>
    </form>
```

In an email to a specified address, and also verifies the contents to be a valid email? Thanks.

Also html5 can validate emails? Is this a better way to go?

Comment: Only in browsers that support the new HTML5 email input option. Basically, *always* have a server-side check, because anyone can simply ignore that input type and send whatever they want.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$email = $_POST['email'];
if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
{
//code to excecute if email is invalid
}
else
{
//code to excecute if email is valid.
}

?>
```

This will use php's inbuilt email address validation.
For javascript/HTML5, have a look at some regular expressions.

Comment: PHP CAN FILTER VARIABLES? ಠ_ಠ

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/).